Why does "Work Offline" turn itself on in SSIS?
I have an SSIS package that is currently working perfectly on my server. Whenever I open it in Visual Studio, "Work Offline" turns itself on for two of the SQL connections. This produces over 100 errors in code that I know to be working perfectly. Said code has multiple connections and it is only these two that have the issue. The two with the issue behave differently:

For one, I can turn Work Offline off and save/rebuilt the package without issue. However, as soon as I close and reopen Visual Studio, it turns itself back on.
For the other, I simply cannot turn Work Offline off. Any attempts to do so give me a "Validating [Step name here]" message at the bottom of my screen. This message never changes. It causes Visual Studio to freeze so badly that it is difficult to kill even with the Task Manager.

I won't ask how to fix this, since it is clearly something magical. Instead, my question is this: How do I begin to debug this problem?

What kind of connections are generating the issues? SQL, File, SMTP?

@MBuschi SQL, specifically to a Microsoft SQL Server.

The connection turn into 'Work offline mode' when you're not able to reach the targets. So probably you're not able to reach the two SQL Server from the machine where you have opended the VS SSIS Projects.
Try to use open them with SSMS using the same connections string and the same authentication method as the ssis is using. In this way you can figure out what is happening.
Probably it is a matter of firewall or authentication.

Seems to be the drivers used by SSIS, but I have no idea why they would have changed.
